# Method error when method called, but not as single line

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I have this method that reports an error at line 7. It runs fine when I enter each line separately in the console, but I get the error when I call the entire `deleteUser` method:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass

```
1 def self.deleteUser(user_id)
2  @user = User.where(:id => user_id).first
3 players = GameMember.where(:user_id => @user.id, :is_game_over => "FALSE")
4
5 if players.empty?
6  stat = Stat.where(:winners_id => @user.id).first
7  unless stat.nil?
8    stat.delete
9 end

  ....
```

Comment: Can you show your invocation code?  `stat` doesn't seem to exist, likely because your `:where` in line 6 is returning no records.

Comment: We need to see the code for where.

Comment: @Senjai looks like ActiveRecord..

Comment: You could do `Stat.where(:winners_id => @user.id).first.try(:delete) if players.empty?`

Comment: Looks like, but should be tagged as such or indicated that it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `unless` needs its own `end`:

```
if ...
  unless stat.nil?
    stat.delete
  end
end
```

You only get to omit the `end` when you use the `x unless y` form:

```
if ...
  stat.delete unless stat.nil?
end
```

(The method itself is lacking an `end`, but I assume you've just omitted that part from your code).